# Selenium click() method on angular.js site

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, click

I am scraping an angular.js site. My initial link has a search button. I find by xpath and click with no issues. After I click search, I want to be able to click each of the athletes in the table to go to their info pages, but I am not having success with the click method. The links are attached to their names.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

TIMEOUT = 5

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(TIMEOUT)
url = 'https://n.rivals.com/search#?formValues=%7B%22sport%22:%22Football%22,%22recruit_year%22:2021,%22offer_and_visit_type%22:%5B%22Offer%22%5D,%22prospect_profiles.prospect_colleges.offer%22:true,%22page_number%22:1,%22page_size%22:50%7D'

try:
    driver.get(url)
except TimeoutException:
    pass

search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="articles"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/div[5]/button')
search_button.click();
#below is where I tried, but could not get to click
first_athlete = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content_"]/td[1]/div[2]/a')
first_athlete.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Works if you remove the last `/a` in the xpath:

```
first_athlete = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content_"]/td[1]/div[2]')
first_athlete.click()
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //*[@id="content_"]/td[1]/div[2]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for all athletes and you have the name of athletes with you, you can use CSS selector as well.

```
athelete = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(`#content_ > td > div > a[href *="donovan-jackson"]);
athelete.click();
```

This code will give you a unique web element for each player.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but I new and a little confused. This is not valid syntax?

Comment: I also can't figure out how to click the next button at the bottom?

Comment: Your syntax was correct, maybe you are testing angular.js site with selenium, there can be synchronization issues. I would suggest adding some wait before performing actions.

Also to click on the Next button, use method to scroll down and then click on the Next button.